# Porting some of the contents to new site. Should I delete the old sitemap.xml?

Tags: google, google-search-console, xml-sitemap

I had a site with multiple blogs for eg www.mysite.com/gre, www.mysite.com/gmat

What I have done is that ported the blogs to new site mynessite.com and set up a 301 redirect. The old content becomes the part of sitemap.xml for new site.
Should I delete the site map for www.mysite.com/gre, www.mysite.com/gmat from my old blog ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just remove the pages that are no longer part of the old site. Search engines periodically re-crawl the sitemaps so there is no need to delete it. Only the obsolete content needs to go.

Comment: So I should delete the old blog directory ? In webamster I can see search engines crawling the old sitemap every couple of days.

Comment: If the blog has moved, and you have your 301 redirects in place, you can delete the blog directory.

Answer (score 1):

If you have implemented proper redirects for all the content of your old websites and nothing is served from these old websites, then yes, you can delete the sitemap(s) from the old websites. Just make sure you have a new one on the new site with new URLs.